Integrating SAP Business One 9.3 with Ariba using Make (Integromat)
I'm working on integrating SAP Business One 9.3 with Ariba using Make (formerly Integromat) and I'm running into some issues. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or examples from those who have done this before.

How do I correctly configure OAuth 2.0 in Make for Ariba?
Are there any existing templates or examples for this type of integration?
What are best practices for error handling in Make?

Thank you in advance for your help!
Best regards,
Authentication:I'm not sure about the correct OAuth 2.0 setup for Ariba API within Make.
Data Mapping: I need help with mapping data fields between Ariba and SAP B1.
Error Handling: Tips on handling errors and retries in Make would be helpful.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
